# Регулярное выражение Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Доброго времени суток,

Нужно составить регулярное выражение для notepad++ для добавления текста после символа, который стоит сразу после найденного значения.
Пример:
Text[Symb]X
Text - искомое значение
Symb - любой один символ после искомого значения
X - текст, который необходимо добавить после символа

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Пример исходного текста:

```
some text
```

Допустим, хотим найти "te". Следующий символ нас не интересует. И надо за этим следующим вставить STR. Тогда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После замены получим:

```
some texSTRt
```

Comment: А зачем вторая группа, если можно все в одну сделать, тем более не опасаться что может пробел выбраться как символ и заменим часть в тексте `...te X`, можно попробовать сделать шаблон поиска ~ `(te[^\t\r\n ])` менять на `$1STR`

Comment: Конечно, можно и так - без "лишних сущностей". Насчет символов перевода на новую строку и возврата каретки не подумал. Касательно табуляции и пробела, - ограничений в условном задании не было.
Любопытно, что Notepad++ в РВ одинаково понимает как обычный пробел, так и \s.